# Problem with regression kriging using the krige command in r

Tags: r, kriging, regression

I want to perform regression kriging in R using gstat. I have a SpatialPointsDataFrame which is of this form:

[image]

After I have run my glm model, in order to see which variables are statistically significant, I end up trying to apply regression kriging with:

```
k = krige(Jan~prop+Lat+dem, st, grd, fit_jan3)
```

`krige` can not see my auxiliary variables, giving me this error message:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'prop' not found.
```

Any help please?

Comment: please replace this picture by a the output of `str(st)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to work, `prop`, `Lat` and `dem` need to be present in `grd` as well. Also, from your question we cannot infer whether `dem` is present in `st`.